# Can SpringMVC create a table from a List<String>?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, html-table

I have a springMVC data (a List):

> "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"

How do I write the jsp file to show the list content in the following table format?

```
 1   2   3   4

 5   6   7   8

 9   10
```

In general, my data are list, or array, and I want to show them in multi-rows with constant number of items per row, say 4 per row.

Comment: You need to understand that this has nothing to do with Spring MVC. It's all about formatting the table for the end user's client. So JSP, HTML, and css are the technologies you should be targeting.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this in JSTL. Test your first tr element using `.index` for 0-based counter and for last element use `.count` for 1-based counter.

```
 <table>
    <c:forEach var="td" items="${list}" varStatus="rowCounter">
    <c:if test="${rowCounter.index mod 4 eq 0}">
        <tr>
    </c:if>
    <td><c:out value="${td}"/></td>
    <c:if test="${(rowCounter.count) mod 4 eq 0}">
        </tr>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

**Note** it will produce a warning which is annoying, but it will produce HTML correctly.
 You can print `<tr>` with `<c:out>` to remove the warning produce by an IDE.

```
<c:out value="<tr>" escapeXml="false" />
```

Whole code would be.

```
<table>
    <c:forEach var="td" items="${list}" varStatus="rowCounter">
    <c:if test="${rowCounter.index mod 4 eq 0}">
      <c:out value="<tr>" escapeXml="false" />
    </c:if>
    <td><c:out value="${td}"/></td>
    <c:if test="${(rowCounter.count) mod 4 eq 0}">
       <c:out value="</tr>" escapeXml="false" />
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: will there be a </tr> missing?

Comment: yep it will produce a warning that has </tr> missing which is annoying, but it output correctly the html. If you want you can use `<c:out>` to remove the warning.I edited my answer

Comment: does it solve your problem? click the check if it was.

Comment: I haven't tried your new method but the old one still works even though the tr are not matched.

Answer (score 2):

**Html code**

```
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <c:forEach var="data" items="${listOfNumbers}" varStatus="loop">
    <td>${data}</td>
            <c:if test="${(loop.count mod 4) == 0}">
                </tr>
                <tr>
            </c:if>

    </c:forEach>
    </tr>
</table>
```

** 4 is the number of colummn you want to show, can be any.

** Need to be precise where and when to close `tr` and `td`.